# Unable to edit custom fields for contacts in wordpress

Tags: contacts, custom-fields

I have had a custom application written to search and display using the API, but since this has happened, I have been unable to edit custom fields in the contacts.

I have checked that I can edit the standard fields fine,, I have tried rolling back the database and files to before the changes, I have cleared cache, I have updated CiviCRM and Wordpress. BUT the issue remains.

I work for a charity and this is their support system for helping their members. Any experts have any Ideas. At this point I am willing to try anything you can think of.

Comment: Have you given access custom data permission?

Comment: This is happening on the super admin account as well as others so it it’s permission related

Comment: it can be frustrating but its worth trying a few things. You mentioned a 'custom application'. It might be worth sharing more about this. If you have rolled everything back and the issue persists then it suggests a OS change i.e. database update/PHP version change or something. Some release notes on the custom app would be worth looking into.

Comment: The custom app just uses css to gather some field values and displays. It basically just searches the database for the fields and then displays using css and api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.
The issue was due to permissions and custom roles being given the permission but not the other account.

This issue is now resolved.
Thank you all for your help and support